# Knit only until a specific chunk

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a way to knit a html_document until a specific chunk?

Suppose I have this .Rmd and I want only to knit a html_document until the `cars` chunk:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Igor Kuivjogi Fernandes"
date: "14/02/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Answer (score 1):

This

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

produces this:

[image]

And if you add one chunk that controls the global options...

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r setup2, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

...then the last code chunk is not executed and there is not plot:

[image]

Comment: @igorkf: I changed my answer to make super clear. And this **is** the answer. If this doesn't work for you, it is not about the `Rmd` code chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way, but isn't so pretty.
I have selected all the code and pressed `Ctrl + Shift + C`, so commented all the lines:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Igor Kuivjogi Fernandes"
date: "14/02/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```
summary(cars)
```

````
<!-- ## Including Plots -->
<!-- You can also embed plots, for example: -->
<!-- ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE} -->
<!-- plot(pressure) -->
<!-- ``` -->
<!-- Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot. -->
````

Answer (score 0):

In case someone lands here. You can check here for a very clear solution.
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-exit.html

`knitr::knit_exit()` is what you probably what you're looking for.